# How to deploy a Helidon application to Google Cloud App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, helidon

I am trying to deploy an Helidon MP project to Google Cloud App Engine using `java11` runtime but having trouble to define the `app.yaml` properly.

1. Tried to deploy the `jar` file directly using the below `app.yaml` using the command `$ gcloud app deploy cord.jar`. The app gets deployed but empty page on view.

   ```
   runtime: java11
   entrypoint: 'java -jar cord.jar'
   ```
2. Tried to modify the codewbase adding `appengine\app.yaml` to `<project>\src\main\appengine\app.yaml` and with contents as below and using command `$ gcloud app deploy pom.xml`:

   ```
   runtime: java11
   instance_class: F1
   ```

In all cases, the app got deployed but page loads empty.

[image]

They have [examples on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11) but unfortunately not yet with Helidon.

Answer (score 2):

I've put [together an example for Helidon](https://github.com/barchetta/helidon-google-app-engine-example/).

A couple things to note:

1. Make sure your application obeys the `PORT` environment variable, and configures its server to use that port.
2. Make sure your `app.yaml` is in the same directory as your jar and defines a custom entry point. For example:

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar helidon-quickstart-se.jar
```

Helidon uses "thin" jars and App Engine seems to handle this AOK as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#application_startup

Answer (score 1):

There is a [github thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/2890) regarding this and so far the current workaround is to add an app.yaml file similar to the one for the frameworks like [Spring Boot](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/springboot-helloworld/src/main/appengine) or [Vert.x](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/vertx-helloworld/src/main/appengine)

I have followed the [tutorial](https://medium.com/helidon/deploying-helidon-applications-to-google-app-engine-61c8d90bdc6a) where the github sample of the other responses is and it worked for me.

First I have cloned the repository and I used the quickstart mp:

```
git clone https://github.com/barchetta/helidon-google-app-engine-example/
cd helidon-google-app-engine-example/helidon-quickstart-mp
```

Then I have built and run the application and check if the port responds.

```
mvn package
export PORT=8888
java -jar target/helidon-quickstart-mp.jar
```

After all these previous steps I was able to see in localhost the result of the application.

For deploying I created the app.yaml file named "helidon-mp-app.yaml" and wrote this configuration inside:

```
runtime: java11
entrypoint: java -Xmx64m -jar helidon-quickstart-mp.jar
```

And copied it to the target/ directory:

```
cp helidon-mp-app.yaml target/
```

As the last configuration file, the file ".gcloudingonre" which also needs to be moved to target/

```
# Exclude everything. Then include just the app jar and runtime
# dependencies in libs/
*
*/
*/**
!helidon-quickstart-mp.jar
!libs/
!libs/**
```

Then as all the configuration files are ready, I executed

```
gcloud app deploy target/helidon-mp-app.yaml
gcloud app browse
```

And appending "/greet" in the URL we can see the result:

> {"message":"Hello World!"}

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to my question.. issue for the page not loading was because of port `9090` that we were using (defined in `src/main/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties` file). After i changed it to default `8080`, my app worked.

`microprofile-config.properties`:

```
# Application properties. This is the default greeting
app.greeting=Hello

# Microprofile server properties
server.port=8080
server.host=0.0.0.0
```

References:

1. [Helidon MP example for Google App Engine](https://github.com/barchetta/helidon-google-app-engine-example/tree/master/helidon-quickstart-mp)